# Set onchange to select with JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to set an atribute onchange with value `auto()` on pure JS or JQuery.

Element name:

```
let autofilling = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling');
```

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let autofilling = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling');
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "[name='butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling']" ).change(function(){
  if(autofilling == 'electro'){
   console.log('test'); 
      
  };
  });
  });
</script>
```

select is in div with id = 'butterbean-control-autofilling' so can I use `let autofilling = document.getElementById('butterbean-control-autofilling').select` ?

Comment: Did you try addEventListener?

Comment: No. How can I add onchange with it?

Comment: What do you think `autofilling` in `if(autofilling=='..` is?  It's not a string, so you can't compare with a string.  If you have an id, you can use `$("#id select")` to get the `select` in that id (or the protracted vanilla-js equivalents).   You might like yo update your question with some HTML and a *clear* statement of what you're trying to achieve and *then* add what you've tried.    This isn't clear: *set an atribute onchange with value auto()*

Comment: `$("[name='butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling']").change(function(){` should work to set a `change event handler` - so depends on your HTML why it's not working or if you're assuming it's not working because you're not getting your `console.log` - remove the erroneous `if (autofilling==` and just have a single `console.log` inside the event handler to make sure that part is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(*your element selector here*)[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function`

Comment: Try with index like in the updated answer

Comment: script is not working: `<script type="text/javascript">
  let autofilling = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling');
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "[name='butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling']" )[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if(autofilling == 'electro'){
   console.log('test'); 
      
  };
  });
  });
</script>`

Comment: `[0].addEventListener` seems a bit long winded for just `.on` - sure if you're using vanilla selections, but if you're using jquery selector, then use jquery events.